# File name match single named export

Tags: eslint

Given the following file, I would like ESlint to require that the name of this file should be `Example.ts`.

```
export class Example {
}
```

I've looked into the [eslint-plugin-filenames](https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames) module, but it only works with defaults.

Is this possible? I am already using `import/group-exports` which means I can't have multiple named exports.

Comment: I am looking for the same functionality, you can vote for the ticket I created in their repo: https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames/issues/47